# Why am I getting this permission denied error when I created the ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I recently created a micro-tier EC2 instance on AWS. I ssh'd into the box with the *.pem key.

I issued a simple command like:

`echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list` and get an error:

```
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list: Permission denied
```

I tried `touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list`

and get:

`touch: cannot touch '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list': Permission denied`

1. If I created the box, aren't I the root user? Or what are the permissions I have by default when I ssh in?
2. How do I make the above commands work?

Answer (score 0):

If you've SSH'ed into the box you'll be the local user (such as `e2-user` or `ubuntu`). By default in Linux you cannot SSH to the root user.

You can confirm this by running the command `whoami` which will return your username.

Simply add `sudo` to the prefix of running the command so for example run the below.

```
sudo echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list
```